# How to trigger a RelayCommand manually in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, relaycommand

I have a code snippet as below:

**XAML**

```
...
<DataGrid>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
           <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownLocationDG}" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class A
{
    public RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> KeyDownLocationDG { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        KeyDownLocationDG = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(TestMethod);

        App.processBarcodeData = new App.ProcessBarCodeData((barcode) =>
        {
            DoSomething();
            // then I ONLY want to trigger KeyDownLocationDG command here
        });
    }

    private void TestMethod(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

I also have a MainWindow.xaml file, there is a `KeyPressed` event of `RawPresentationInput` object in the code-behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs). Everytime this event fired, I'll call `processBarcodeData` delegate. If I press a key on DataGrid, the `TestMethod` will be executed immediately, but I don't want to do that, what I want is to make it can only run after DoSomething() done.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for synchronizing two `KeyPressed` events?

Comment: Maybe you can use the `CanExecute` of the `ICommand`, check an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/782169/Attributed-RelayCommand), and the DoSomething method can set a property like "Done" when is done, that you will use to enable/disable the command.

Comment: @Dzyann: Oh that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid.PreviewKeyDown` event is called earlier that `Window.KeyPress`.

Either use `PreviewKeyDown` event in MainWindow, or specify all the actions in the grid:

```
<DataGrid>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
           <mvvm:CallMethodAction Method="DoSomething" />
           <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownLocationDG}" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</DataGrid>`
```

In the second case you should also set `KeyEventArgs.IsHandled = true;` in order to prevent bubling the event down to Window, but it may have undesired effects

Answer (score 6):

`RelayCommand` is an `ICommand`, and like all other `ICommand` classes you just call it's `Execute()` function.

Comment: Title must be misleading, read the question, it is not about command execution.